# Django admin change list integration with change form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Basically I have a structure of 3 models in the order:

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    # (actually, it doesn't matter what type m_aid is...)
    m_aid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # ...

class Model_B(models.Model):
    m_bid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # same as previous
    m_a = models.ForeignKey('Model_A', db_column='m_aid')
    # ...

class Model_C(models.Model):
    m_cid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # same as the previous 2
    m_b = models.ForeignKey('Model_B', db_column='m_bid')
    # ...
```

What I'm looking for is to use the admin change form templates with a slight difference: in the change_form of Model_A I want to show the change list of its child - Model_B and in the change_form of Model_B I would like to put the change list of Model_C.

Any ideas how to do it?

P.S You might see it as a silly question, but I'm new to django(and python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to accomplish that.

They will allow you to edit one or more instances of "Model B" when editing an instance of "Model A" and so on. It's not identical to what you see in the change list, but there are two built-in layouts, stacked and tabular, for inlines. Tabular will get you closest in appearance to what you want.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want them to be editable. I need them to look the same as if I would access theirs change_list page but within the parent's change_form

Comment: You can always make the fields readonly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields, or you could override the inline template and do whatever you want. Django is very flexible in this regard.

Comment: Making fields readonly wouldn't solve the problem as I want to be able to add a new Model_B to Model_A. Now, I wonder if overriding the inline template will allow me to implement the same functionality as those in the default change_list, such as checkboxes, actions and the add button.

Comment: You can always override the templates and even dynamically add url patterns and views to a Model's admin. Even if you made the fields readonly, you could still add an new "Model B" to a "Model A". Readonly fields only apply for existing model instances.